# Spark and categorical string variables

Tags: apache-spark, logistic-regression, categorical-data, apache-spark-ml

I'm trying to understand how spark.ml handles string categorical independent variables.  I know that in Spark I have to convert strings to doubles using [StringIndexer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#stringindexer).
Eg., "a"/"b"/"c" => 0.0/1.0/2.0.
But what I really would like to avoid is then having to use [OneHotEncoder](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#onehotencoder) on that column of doubles. This seems to make the pipeline unnecessarily messy. Especially since Spark knows that the data is categorical. Hopefully the sample code below makes my question clearer.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression

val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
Tuple2(0.0,"a"), Tuple2(1.0, "b"), Tuple2(1.0, "c"), Tuple2(0.0, "c")
)).toDF("y", "x")

// index the string column "x"
val indexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("x").setOutputCol("xIdx").fit(df)
val indexed = indexer.transform(df)

// build a data frame of label, vectors
val assembler = (new VectorAssembler()).setInputCols(List("xIdx").toArray).setOutputCol("features")
val assembled = assembler.transform(indexed)

// build a logistic regression model and fit it
val logreg = (new LogisticRegression()).setFeaturesCol("features").setLabelCol("y")
val model = logreg.fit(assembled)
```

The logistic regression sees this as a model with only one independent variable.

```
model.coefficients
res1: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector = [0.7667490491775728]
```

But the independent variable is categorical with three categories = ["a", "b", "c"]. I know I never did a one of k encoding but the metadata of the data frame knows that the feature vector is nominal.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.attribute.AttributeGroup
AttributeGroup.fromStructField(assembled.schema("features"))
res2: org.apache.spark.ml.attribute.AttributeGroup = {"ml_attr":{"attrs":
{"nominal":[{"vals":["c","a","b"],"idx":0,"name":"xIdx"}]},
"num_attrs":1}}
```

How do I pass this information to [LogisticRegression](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression)? Is this not the whole point of keeping dataframe metadata? There does not seem to be a [CategoricalFeaturesInfo](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-decision-tree.html#problem-specification-parameters) in SparkML. Do I really need to do a 1 of k encoding for each categorical feature?

Comment: Why can't you use one-hot encoding directly on the strings? Some models explicitly allow categorical features, but logistic regression expects continuous features (e.g, mappings of a:0, b:1, c:2, imply c is twice as much as b)

Comment: OneHotEncoder is expecting a column of `DoubleType`. See also the example of [OneHotEncoder](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#onehotencoder) where they first transform using StringIndexer and then OneHotEncoder.

Comment: Yes, you really need the encoding.

Comment: Good answer to my long winded question :). In that case can you explain a little bit about what the point of that meta data is? Where will the fact that the first entry of this vector is actually a nominal variable named "xIdx" with vals = ["c", "a", "b"] get used?

Comment: :) The only usage I am aware of is label validation.  While theoretically  it could be possible to use if for automatic encoding it would have to run every time you train a model and couldn't be cached. And you cannot avoid it completely and use only metadata because the output for linear models is simply a matrix. It doesn't really distinguish between categorical or numerical variables at this point. It could be (although it is not right now) use to extract required info for tree models.

Comment: I don't understand your point about caching. What's the difference between me explicitly encoding the dataframe and spark.ml doing it implicitly and then passing it to the estimator? There is still a data frame object that can be cached.

Comment: responding to your comment#2, not clear what you are asking- you need to do the one hot encoding (or equivalent method), but sounds like to do your own category mapping? It's a simple enough concept to combine into one function that takes a string.

Comment: @zero323 It actually is used right now to extract information for tree models . See [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#decision-trees). One of the main differences between ml and mllib implementations is the "use of DataFrame metadata to distinguish continuous and categorical features"

Comment: Good point. I missed that :) So we have two cases where it is used.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am missing something, but this really looks like the job for RFormula (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#rformula).

As the name suggests, it takes an "R-style" formula that describes how the feature vector is composed from the input data columns.

For each categorical input columns (that is, StringType as type) it adds a StringIndexer + OneHotEncoder to the final pipeline implementing the formula under the hoods.

The output is a feature vector (of doubles) that can be used with any algorithm in the org.apache.spark.ml package, as the one you are targeting.